# How can I populate a form with results from one table which can be edited and saved to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The answers to date have not worked so I have re-written my request for help.  I hope it is more clear what I am struggling with

I want to move fields from an array (Array1) returned from a table(Table1) into another array (Array2), allow edit and write each record to Table2.

Desired methodology in /new_multiple in the controller:
   1. @tasks = Task.find(params[:task_ids]) # returns multiple records
                                         #:task_ids are checkbox tags
                                         #returned from previous form
   Note:   This works.
   2. Move @tasks each into @event and send to existing new.html.erb form for edit and/or confirmation before creation as follows(??):

```
   @tasks.each do |task|
      @event = Event.new
      @event.location = task.task_location
      @event.description =  task.task_description
      event.start_date = start_date + task.days_from_from_start_task
      .....   more calculated fields
      ***send to form for edit, show, create and return for next record  (QUESTION 1 below)
   end
```

Note:   a redirect and return in *** goes to the form, but the data does not show in the form.    I haven't determined if it actually returns.

Questions:
      1.  Is there a way call a form from the middle of an iteration in the controller and then return to the loop for other records?
      2.  If not, how do I (can I?) 
          a)move the multiple @tasks records into an @events array as above (for display in a table in a form for edit)
          b)tell the system that each individual row of the array is a new record to be written on submit

**Background:**

I am creating an application which allows the scheduling of sets of future events.   Related tasks (sets) are saved in one table and specify a sequence and a number of days from the first task in the group for that task to occur.

The user starts the process by setting the criteria - task group and the start date from which the events will begin.

The task records are then displayed with the calculated dates/time in a table on a form using a form_tag.  At this point, they look like the events that are going to be created.   Each line has a check-box tag for selection of tasks in the group.   After the user has "ticked" their selection of events (or all), the application returns to the controller to a method called new_multiple_events

Up to this point everything works fine and I can see the selected records that have been chosen (ticked) within the events controller using debugger.

I now want to display each record individually and allow the user to edit the calculated date and time that the event will occur plus a few other fields such as the location and notes etc. and then submit the record for creation in the events table.  But this is where I am just NOT getting it.
Models:
          Tasks table model:

```
      task.task_description                     
      task.task_location                        
      task.task_notes                           
      task.days_from_start_task
      task.task_group_name

      Event table model:

      event.title = task.task_group_name
      event.location = task.task_location
      event.description = task.task_notes
      event.start_date = start_date + task.days_from_from_start_task
      etc...
```

I have a form which works fine for entry of individual events into the calendar and I would like to move the data from the returned tasks array (plus calculated fields) into the events array as default values for this form which will then allow the user to save the data.

Thanking you in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: i think you might find [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) useful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am closing this issue because I didn't receive a relevant answer.   I wanted to allow editing of selected data from one table prior to writing the data, with additional information, to another table.  To get around the issue I have instead saved the selected data to the other table and then immediately read the data for edit/update.  To the user it looks the same.

Comment: This does not appear to be an answer to your own question but a work around. Even though this question was asked over a month ago, you should leave it open and not close it with a non-relevant answer. Someone may come along and provide an answer that would be useful not just to you, but to others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are prepopulating the event you are editing / creating in the form, but your code states you are doing that in a model. You should however create that logic in the controller before rendering the form, so do something like this:

## events_controller.rb

```
def new
  task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
  @event = Event.new
  @event.title = task.task_group_name
  @event.location = task.task_location
  @event.description = task.task_notes
  @event.start_date = start_date + task.days_from_from_start_task
end
```

Then create your form like you normally do with the form declaration you already found yourself: `form_for @event do |f|`

Please consider that I used params[:task_id], suggesting you set up your routes for events nested under tasks so that your url structure looks like (for instance): /tasks/13/events/new

Goog luck

Comment: Thank you for your response, bo-oz.    I return :task_ids from the previous form

Comment: There was more to that comment:  Thank you for your response, @bo-oz.    I return a plural  :task_ids from the previous form since the user will have "ticked" several lines.  I have tried two similar approaches by putting an iteration within the new_multiple section of the controller and redirecting to /new - populating within /new vs populating within the loop and then redirecting.   I'll try again as it may have been an unrelated issue.  I'll update this again with code if it doesn't work